# JS Setting onclick attribute using different methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to set an onclick attribute to an anchor like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $(this).onclick = "ItWorks";
    output = "JS onclick attempt: my onclick is: <strong>" + $(this).onclick + "</strong>";
    $(this).prop("onclick", "ItWorks");
    output += "<br />jQuery prop() attempt: my onclick is: <strong>" + $(this).prop("onclick") + "</strong>";
    $(this).attr("onclick", "ItWorks");
    output += "<br />jQuery attr() attempt: my onclick is: <strong>" + $(this).attr("onclick") + "</strong>";

    alert(output);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've tried pure JS, jQuery prop() and attr() functions. As you can see on this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekAex/), only .attr() function works as it should.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong that the other two attempts return "null" or "undefined"?

Comment: What is the world is `$a`? also onclick is a bad idea! because it is an event!

Comment: @epascarello sorry, that was remains from the fiddle, already corrected. I need an onclick because it's for pageTracker purpose

Comment: try to use $(this).attr("onclick", "ItWorks()");

Comment: the onclick's value have to be passed as a string like this: "pageTracker._trackEvent('category', 'subcategory')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$(this).onclick = "ItWorks";`

Sets a property on the JQuery object, not the DOM node.

> `$(this).prop("onclick", "ItWorks");`

Sets the property to a string, but it expects a function … and the property does not map directly onto the attribute value as it does for some other properties.

> `$(this).attr("onclick", "ItWorks");`

Sets the attribute to a string, although not one that will do anything when executed as JS.

If you want to set an event handler and are using jQuery, then use [the `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and don't try to test it by examining the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it easier:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='clickEvent("a")'>link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='clickEvent("a")'>link</a>

function clickEvent(event)  {
   if (event == "a") {
     output = "event a clicked";
   } elseif (event == "b") {
     output = "event b clicked";
   }
   alert(output);

}
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use it because there's a lot of rendering objects from xml file and switches and ifs and god only knows what else. Great solution though, thanks!